# How to disallow all files & folder and allow for some in robots.txt?

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

I need `robots.txt` commends doing the next:

1. disallow all files and folders
2. allow just to `index.php` & `msub.php`

I have edit the links for `msub.php` i did `RewriteReuls` from `.htaccess` to be like:

domain.com/p/subject122

domain.com/p/subject104

So i want make the links show up in search engines just like: domain.com/p/subject122 .

How can i do that?

I have tried this commands but not works as well.. The links : `domain.com/p/subject104` not show up in search engines

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /index.php
Allow: /msub.php
```

.htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error.html [L]

RewriteRule home /index.php 
RewriteRule p/(.*)$ msub.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question

Comment: Yes sure.......

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 1):

`robots.txt` should contain URIs that are seen by crawlers, no matter how you handle them internally. So your `robots.txt` should have:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /p/subject122
Allow: /p/subject104
```

Your .htaccess can be refactored as well:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^404/?$$ error.html [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule p/(.*)$ msub.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: That's not gonna work because the URLs is dynamic not static i can't add URLs manually to robots.txt..

Comment: In that case why even bother about robots file. Modern search engines are smart enough to cache valid uRLs only

Comment: Yes you are  right.. search engines  can catch it but what about other private files in the host!? Its will displaying on search also, that's the problem

Comment: No, private files will NEVER be cached by search engines. Please understand how web crawlers work. They will follow links from root page of your website. If you publish e.g. 5 links in your entire website then search engine will cache only those 5 URLs.

Comment: I was have .txt files i didn't have published or using it in my website or any other web pages ... I shocker it's available in google results! How Google search engine catched? That files are private i don't want to share it !

Comment: You can probably get details in some google tool on how it is caching some  internal files that are not even linked on your website. Sorry, I am not really a SEO expert.